# Configure grafana cloudwatch datasource with STS Temporary credentials

Tags: grafana, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, aws-sts

Is there a way to configure Grafana Cloudwatch datasource using AWS STS Temporary credentials?

I am trying to configure a cloudwatch datasource in grafana by assuming a role. I have created a role CLoudwatchGrafanaRole which has policies defined to read metrics from Cloudwatch.

Next I created a IAM user grafana and defined the following policy for the user

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:I am::<>:role/CloudwatchGrafanaRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also modified the trust policy of CloudwatchGrafanaRole

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:Iam::<>:user/grafana"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Next, using AWS CLI fetch the access id, key and session token

```
aws configure //login with grafana user 

aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<>:role/CloudwatchGrafanaRole --role-session-name "RoleSession1"
```

From the above command we get AWS Access ID, key and session token.

How do you use them to configure datasource in grafana?

Trying to use the Temporary Access ID and secret key directly returns the error - 1. CloudWatch metrics query failed: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid. status code: 403

Also, the .aws/credentials file is empty inside the grafana docker image

Grafana version=9.4.1

Comment: Why you dont use that user and assumed role directly in the datasource configuration ?

Comment: Assume a role authentication is available only with grafana v10, right? I am using v9.4. Did I understand it correctly or am i missing something

Comment: No, it should be available in Grafana 9 as well.

Comment: Assume a Role Authentication is not listed in Grafana docs v9.4 - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.4/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/aws-authentication/#select-an-authentication-method 
Grafana v10 - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/aws-authentication/#select-an-authentication-method

Maybe I understood it wrong. Are you talking about authenticating through STS temporary credentials?

Comment: It's in the doc:https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.4/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/aws-authentication/#assume-a-role

Comment: Assume a Role takes IAM Role ARN. That is fine. But what about the authentication field while configuring the datasource? I don't want to go with Access key id and secret